# two question about uniformly convergence of sums

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

**First question:**

I want to show that this series :
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^k}$$

converges uniformly in $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$.

I thought about the M test and i get : $\frac{x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^k}\:\le \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2\right)^k}\:=\frac{1}{\left(x^2\right)^{k-1}}\le \frac{1}{\left(a^2\right)^{k-1}}$
therefore, the function-sum converge. It is good enough?

**Second question:**
For the sum above, how can i show that the sum **does not** converge uniformly in $[-a,a]$ for any $a>0$?

Comment: Show the limit function is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: why it is not? the limit function is not $\equiv 0$?

Comment: The terms of the series tend to $0$, but the series itself doesn't.

Comment: This cant be true since the first parts of the sum are positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second question: One way is to show the convergence is not uniform on $[-a,a]$, $a>0$ is to show that the limit function is not continuous at $0$.

You can explicitly evaluate the limit function $f$:

$f(0)=0$.

For $x\ne0$, $f(x)=1+x^2$. (Use the formula for the sum of a Geometric series here.)

For your first question, your approximation is too loose. What if $|a|<1$? Then the relevant sum in the $M$-test does not converge.

But, you can use the formula for the sum of a Geometric series to show $\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty {x^2\over(1+x^2)^k}$ is uniformly small for large $n$
(I calculated  the sum is ${1\over (1+x^2)^{n-1}}\le {1\over (1+a)^{n-1}}$ for $x\in[a,\infty)$).